# how to calculate the previous total with the current total with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to calculate every month with the previous months like:

```
Jan: 5000

Feb: 2000 +(5000 from Jan) = 7000
```

for each account.

so how can I do it, I tried to extract the totals by each month but I didn't get any result.

DDLs:

```
CREATE TABLE `tblregs1` (
`RegID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`RegRef` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`RegCode` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`RegDate` date NOT NULL,
`RegCurr` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `tblregs1` (`RegID`, `RegRef`, `RegCode`, `RegDate`, `RegCurr`,         
`RegDetails`, `RegType`, `RegStatus`) VALUES
(1, 202010011140192, '', '2020-10-01', 1),
(2, 202010011141252, '', '2020-10-01', 1),
(3, 202010011141562, '', '2020-10-01', 1),
(4, 202010011143242, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(5, 202010010103422, '', '2020-10-01', 1),
(6, 202010020836472, '', '2020-10-01', 0),
(7, 202010030101142, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(8, 202010030101272, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(9, 202010030101392, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(10, 202010030101522, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(11, 202010030102112, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(12, 202010030153562, '', '2020-10-03', 1),
(14, 202010030158322, '', '2020-10-03', 1),
(15, 202010030431432, '', '2020-10-02', 0),
(16, 202010030439122, '', '2020-10-01', 1),
(17, 202010030512263, '', '2020-10-01', 1),
(18, 202010030515133, '', '2020-10-03', 2),
(19, 202010041255541, '', '2020-10-02', 1);

CREATE TABLE `tblregs2` (
`RegdID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`RegRef` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
`RegdM1` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RegdD1` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RegdAccID` int(11) NOT NULL,
`RegdDetails` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`RegdCurrPrice` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RegdM2` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RegdD2` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RecStatus` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Normal',
`RegdNo` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
`RegdMtbkRaseed` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RegdMtbkFark` double NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`RegdMtbkStatus` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`RegdMtbkNotes` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

INSERT INTO `tblregs2` (`RegdID`, `RegRef`, `RegdM1`, `RegdD1`,      
`RegdAccID`, `RegdDetails`, `RegdCurrPrice`, `RegdM2`, `RegdD2`,     
`RecStatus`, `RegdNo`, `RegdMtbkRaseed`, `RegdMtbkFark`, `RegdMtbkStatus`, 
`RegdMtbkNotes`) VALUES
(1, 202010011140192, 1000, 0, 916, 'Des1', 1, 1000, 0, 'Normal', 0, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(4, 202010011141252, 0, 10000, 32, 'Des1', 1, 0, 10000, 'Normal', 2, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(13, 202010011143242, 1680, 0, 32, 'Des1', 1, 1680, 0, 'Normal', 3, -8320, 
0, 'no', 'no'),
(14, 202010011143242, 0, 1680, 15, 'Des1', 1, 0, 1680, 'Normal', 4, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(16, 202010011143242, 0, 10, 32, 'Des1', 1, 0, 10, 'Normal', 6, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(17, 202010011143242, 15, 0, 32, 'Des1', 1, 15, 0, 'Normal', 7, -8315, 0, 
'', '-8315'),
(19, 202010011143242, 450000, 0, 32, 'Des1', 1235, 364.37, 0, 'Normal', 9, 
0, 0, '', ''),
(20, 202010011143242, 0, 450000, 306, 'Des1', 1, 0, 450000, 'Normal', 10, 
0, 0, NULL, NULL),
(33, 202010020836472, 0, 0, 916, '', 0, 0, 0, 'Normal', 9, 0, 0, NULL, 
NULL),
(34, 202010020836472, 0, 0, 86, '', 0, 0, 0, 'Normal', 10, 0, 0, NULL, 
NULL),
(35, 202010030153562, 1400, 0, 32, 'Des1', 32, 1400, 0, 'Normal', 0, 
-6550.63, 0, '', '12'),
(36, 202010030153562, 0, 1400, 55, 'Des1', 55, 0, 1400, 'Normal', 0, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(38, 202010030158322, 0, 7000, 32, 'Des1', 1, 0, 7000, 'Normal', 2, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(64, 202010041255541, 0, 4500, 32, 'Des1', 1, 0, 4500, 'Normal', 2, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(65, 202010041255541, 10, 0, 33, 'Des1', 1, 10, 0, 'Normal', 3, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL),
(66, 202010041255541, 0, 10, 45, 'Des1', 1, 0, 10, 'Normal', 4, 0, 0, 
NULL, NULL);
```

example of my data for the specified user is:

```
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
| RegID |  RegDate  | RegdID | RegdAccID | RegdM2 | RegdD2 |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
|   2   | 10/1/2020 |    4   |     32    |    0   |  10000 |
|   4   | 10/2/2020 |   13   |     32    |  1680  |    0   |
|   4   | 10/2/2020 |   16   |     32    |    0   |   10   |
|   4   | 10/2/2020 |   17   |     32    |   15   |    0   |
|   4   | 10/2/2020 |   19   |     32    | 364.37 |    0   |
|   12  | 10/3/2020 |   35   |     32    |  1400  |    0   |
|   14  | 10/3/2020 |   38   |     32    |    0   |  7000  |
|   19  | 10/2/2020 |   64   |     32    |    0   |  4500  |
+-------+-----------+--------+-----------+--------+--------+
```

this is the result that gives me:

```
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
|  RegDate  |RegdAccID| RegdM2 | RegdD2 |   Result  |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
| 10/1/2020 |    4   |    0   |  10000 |   -10000  |
| 10/2/2020 |   13   |  1680  |    0   |   -8320   |
| 11/2/2020 |   13   |    0   |   10   |   -8330   |
| 10/2/2020 |   17   |   15   |    0   |   -8315   |
| 11/2/2020 |   17   | 364.37 |    0   |  -7950.63 |
| 11/2/2020 |   17   |    0   |  4500  | -18050.63 |
| 10/3/2020 |   35   |  1400  |    0   |  -6550.63 |
| 11/3/2020 |   35   |    0   |  7000  | -13550.63 |
+-----------+--------+--------+--------+-----------+
```

what I need now is:
how to calculate the previous total with the current total for each account and month.
I tried the next code but it didn't work, it gives me the wrong numbers:

```
SELECT 
    d.RegdAccID,
    MONTH(d.RegDate) AS xMonth, 
    d.AccName, 
    IF(@w = d.RegdAccID,
    CAST(@s := @s + d.RegdM2-d.RegdD2 AS DECIMAL(15,2)),
    CAST(@s := 0 + d.RegdM2-d.RegdD2 AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS Raseed,
    (@w := d.RegdAccID) as x
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        a.RegDate,  
        a.RegRef,  
        b.RegdAccID, 
        b.RegdM2, 
        b.RegdD2, 
        n.AccName
    FROM tblregs2 b
    INNER JOIN tblregs1 a ON b.RegRef = a.RegRef
    INNER JOIN tblaccounts n ON n.AccID = b.RegdAccID
    WHERE 
    (b.RegdM2>0 or b.RegdD2>0)) d
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s := 0) c
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @w := 0) i
GROUP BY d.RegdAccID,xMonth
ORDER BY d.RegdAccID,xMonth
```

Comment: If you're using MySQL 8.0 I think you should be able to do this with window functions.

Comment: @Barmar my version is: Server version: 10.4.11-MariaDB, how to use window functions?

Comment: Window functions were added in MariaDB 10.2. So you should be able to use them.

Comment: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/window-functions/

Comment: @Barmar sorry but I didn't understand you well, what I should use exactly with it, what I need is just correct the SQL to get the correct result, so I need to advise me more

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64725254/how-to-calculate-the-previous-total-with-the-current-total-with-group-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved part of the issue:

```
SELECT 
                                    month(d.RegDate) AS xMonth,  
                                    d.RegdAccID,                                  
                                    d.AccName,(@ss + SUM(d.Raseed)) xras
FROM 
                                    (SELECT 
                                    a.RegDate, 
   

                             b.RegdAccID, 
                                b.RegdM2, 
                                b.RegdD2, 
                                n.AccName,
                                IF(@w = b.RegdAccID,
                                CAST(@s := @s + b.RegdM2-b.RegdD2 AS DECIMAL(15,2)),
                                CAST(@s := 0 + b.RegdM2-b.RegdD2 AS DECIMAL(15,2))) AS Raseed,
                                (@w := b.RegdAccID) as x 
                                 
                                FROM tblregs2 b
                                INNER JOIN tblregs1 a ON b.RegRef = a.RegRef
                                INNER JOIN tblaccounts n ON n.AccID = b.RegdAccID  
                                WHERE 
                                (b.RegdM2>0 or b.RegdD2>0) AND b.RegdAccID=112) d
                                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s := 0) c
                                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @ss := 0) cc
                                CROSS JOIN (SELECT @w := 0) i
                                GROUP BY xMonth
                                ORDER BY 
                                d.RegdAccID,xMonth
```

but I want the CurrentTotal to be (PreviousTotal+Current)

Answer (score 0):

You provide code for two tables, examples of data from one, and a query that references three.  That makes it really hard to follow what you are trying to do.  Let me assume that the subquery in your larger query is really the data you are working with.

If so, you can just use window functions.  I think the code is:

```
SELECT r1.RegDate, r1.RegRef,
       r2.RegdAccID, r2.RegdM2, r2.RegdD2, 
       a.AccName,
       sum(RegdM2 - RegdD2) over (partition by r1.RegdAccID order by r1.regdate, r2.regdid)
FROM tblregs2 r2 JOPIN
     tblregs1 r1
     ON r2.RegRef = r1.RegRef JOIN
     tblaccounts a
     ON a.AccID = r1.RegdAccID
WHERE r2.RegdM2 > 0 OR r2.RegdD2 > 0;
```

I'm not 100% sure about the `partition by` columns, but the account id seems reasonable to me.